# Multiple automatic updating series from JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

I try to plot 3 temperature series into a single highcharts chart.
The data comes from 3 seperate JSON files in the format:

```
[
[1567529940953,43.4],
[1567530001644,43.3],
[1567530062503,43.4],
[1567530123220,43.4],
[1567530184116,43.4]
]
```

Additionally the JSON file is periodically updated so I want the chart to update itself every time the JSON files change or every minute or so.
I looked into enablePolling and that works perfect.

I have tried a lot but or I have multiple series and no polling or I have a single series and polling....

The best I could do was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 2,
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 12,
                        text: '12h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }]
                },
            title: {
                text: 'Live Data (Rows JSON)'
            },
            yAxis: {
                    min: 15,
                    max: 50,
                    startOnTick: false,
                    endOnTick: false
                },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Data input from a remote JSON file'
            },

            data: {
                rowsURL: window.location.origin + '/chart/terrarium_basking.json',
                firstRowAsNames: false,
                enablePolling: true
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I needed to use window.location.origin in order to get it to work on my website. Not sure why www.reptile-addict.nl/chart/terrarium_basking.json didn't work!?
If it helps the other JSON streams are terrarium_ambient.json and terrarium_ceiling.json

EDIT: Think I got it to work.. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>


        <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var seriesOptions = [],
                seriesCounter = 0,
                names = ['basking','ambient','ceiling'];

            /**
            * Create the chart when all data is loaded
            * @returns {undefined}
            */
            function createChart() {
                Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
                    series: seriesOptions
                });
            }

            function getJsonData() {
                        $.each(names, function (i, name) {

                        path = window.location.origin + '/chart/terrarium_' + name + '.json';

                        $.getJSON(path,    function (data) {
                            seriesOptions[i] = {
                                name: name,
                                data: data
                            };

                            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
                            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
                            seriesCounter += 1;

                            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                                createChart();
                                seriesCounter = 0;
                            }
                        });
                        });
            }

            getJsonData();

            setInterval( function(){ getJsonData(); }, 60000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Try to simplify your chart and use static data with the same structure as your dynamic data (using setTimeout to make fake dynamic data).

Comment: It is basically this example but with multiple external json files polling: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-rows

Comment: Ok, but this example works perfectly and not present your issue. You can just update the chart when a new JSON is loaded, without using `data.rowsURL`.

Comment: It shows what I try to achieve but it uses a single JSON creating a single serie. I want to have multiple JSONs with seperate series in a single chart. 
You say: "You can just update the chart when a new JSON is loaded, without using data.rowsURL" but I havn't got a clue on how to accomplish that :( Atleast not without having to reload the entire page in the browser.

Comment: Think I got it. I'm using setInterval() to rebuild the graph every minute. Any better solutions?

Comment: The better idea is to update data using `series.setData`, `series.update` or `chart.update`. Check these API links: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData, https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update, https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update